# An alternative to sp_msforeachdb

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, sp-msforeachdb

​I inherited the script below and struggling to run this against all databases across different instances.

It works when I use sp_msforeachdb but it does not output the way I want it to and it also includes blank result sets for databases
with no data which is part of the problem of using sp_msforeachdb...

I feel it's my joins which I have tried different forms but still not outputting the way I want. Kindly review and give feedback.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @cmd1 nvarchar(2000)
set @cmd1 =
'use ?;
SELECT ''?''
       DatabaseName,
       [File Name],
       [Physical Name],
       [File - Total Size In MB],
       [File - Available Space In MB],
       [Filegroup Name],
       [Disk Mount Point],
       [Disk Total Size in GB],
       [Disk Available Size in GB],
       [Disk Free Space % ],
       Growth,
       NextGrowthRequirementInMB,
       FileSpaceAfterGrowthMB 
    FROM
       (
          SELECT
             DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName,
             f.[file_id],
             f.name AS [File Name],
             f.physical_name AS [Physical Name],
             CAST((f.size / 128.0) AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) 
             AS [File - Total Size In MB],
             CAST(f.size / 128.0 -
             CAST(FILEPROPERTY(f.name, 'SpaceUsed') AS int) 
             / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) 
             AS [File - Available Space In MB],
             fg.name AS [Filegroup Name],
             volume_mount_point [Disk Mount Point],
             CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2),
            total_bytes / 1073741824.0) 
            AS [Disk Total Size in GB],
             ---1GB = 1073741824 bytes 
            CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),available_bytes/1073741824.0) 
            AS [Disk Available Size in GB], 
             CAST(CAST(available_bytes AS FLOAT) 
            / CAST(total_bytes AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(18, 2))
             * 100 AS [Disk Free Space % ],
             f.Growth,
             CASE
                f.is_percent_growth 
                WHEN
                   0 
                THEN
                   f.Growth / 128 
                WHEN
                   1 
                THEN
                   f.growth 
                 / 100.00*CAST((f.size / 128.0) AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) 
             END
             AS NextGrowthRequirementInMB, 
             CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), total_bytes 
             / 1073741824.0) - (
             CASE
                f.is_percent_growth 
                WHEN
                   0 
                THEN
                   f.Growth / 128 
                WHEN
                   1 
                THEN
                   f.growth 
                / 100.00*CAST((f.size / 128.0) AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) 
             END
    ) AS FileSpaceAfterGrowthMB,
  f.is_percent_growth, 
  file_system_type [File System Type] 
          FROM
             sys.database_files AS f WITH (NOLOCK) 
             INNER JOIN
                sys.master_files m 
                on f.file_id = m.file_id 
             LEFT OUTER JOIN
                sys.data_spaces AS fg WITH (NOLOCK) 
                ON f.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id 
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(database_id, m.file_id) 
          WHERE
             m.database_id = DB_ID()) a
where DB_NAME() NOT IN(''master'',''model'',''msdb'',
                       ''tempdb'',''xx'',''xxx'',''xxxx'')
     ORDER BY 1 desc'

EXEC sp_foreachdb @command = @cmd1
GO
```

Comment: This question is too broad. What exact problem are you having? "not outputting the way I want" doesn't help me understand what you are seeking to do

Comment: Welcome to SO! A few tips here. 1) Format your code. It really helps. 2) Explain *it does not output the way i want*. We can't read your mind. 3) What would you expect the results to be for a database that didn't have any data in it? I'd expect it to be blank... 4) Consider [Aaron's version of sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) 5) [Read How to create a MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sorry for now being clear. When I run the script as is it returns only data for the database I am currently connected to and when I try to run it via registered server it does the same. When I wrap it with sp_MSforeachdb via registered servers it outputs all the databases but not in order of the instances/servername and when I exclude system databases it outputs blanks plus the list of databases and again not in order of instances. I hope this helps and your assistance is much appreciated. In the meantime I will go through suggestions.

Comment: I have updated the script to show how I wrapped it with sp_foreachdb which I downloaded from Brent Ozar Unlimited and executed against all the SQL instances that I am trying to extract information from. I get the results in different grids but want the results sorted by instance/servername instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon after `USE ?;` that is why you are getting results always from the same database.

To exclude the system tables, `sp_foreachdb` already has a parameter named `@user_only`, you don't need the where at the end

Also, your query is larger than 2000 characters

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @cmd1 nvarchar(max)
DROP TABLE #TMP
CREATE TABLE #TMP (DatabaseName VARCHAR(100),
       [File Name] VARCHAR(200),
       [Physical Name] VARCHAR(200),
       [File - Total Size In MB] FLOAT,
       [File - Available Space In MB] FLOAT,
       [Filegroup Name] VARCHAR(50),
       [Disk Mount Point]  VARCHAR(50),
       [Disk Total Size in GB] FLOAT,
       [Disk Available Size in GB] FLOAT,
       [Disk Free Space % ] FLOAT,
       Growth FLOAT,
       NextGrowthRequirementInMB FLOAT,
       FileSpaceAfterGrowthMB FLOAT)
set @cmd1 =
'use ?
INSERT #TMP
SELECT 
       DatabaseName,
       [File Name],
       [Physical Name],
       [File - Total Size In MB],
       [File - Available Space In MB],
       [Filegroup Name],
       [Disk Mount Point],
       [Disk Total Size in GB],
       [Disk Available Size in GB],
       [Disk Free Space % ],
       Growth,
       NextGrowthRequirementInMB,
       FileSpaceAfterGrowthMB 
    FROM
       (
          SELECT
             DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName,
             f.[file_id],
             f.name AS [File Name],
             f.physical_name AS [Physical Name],
             CAST((f.size / 128.0) AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) AS [File - Total Size In MB],
             CAST(f.size / 128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(f.name, ''SpaceUsed'') AS int) / 128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) AS [File - Available Space In MB],
             fg.name AS [Filegroup Name],
             volume_mount_point [Disk Mount Point],
             CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), total_bytes / 1073741824.0) AS [Disk Total Size in GB],
             ---1GB = 1073741824 bytes 
             CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),available_bytes/1073741824.0) AS [Disk Available Size in GB], 
             CAST(CAST(available_bytes AS FLOAT) / CAST(total_bytes AS FLOAT) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)) * 100 AS [Disk Free Space % ],
             f.Growth,
             CASE
                f.is_percent_growth 
                WHEN
                   0 
                THEN
                   f.Growth / 128 
                WHEN
                   1 
                THEN
                   f.growth / 100.00*CAST((f.size / 128.0) AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) 
             END
             AS NextGrowthRequirementInMB, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), total_bytes / 1073741824.0) - (
             CASE
                f.is_percent_growth 
                WHEN
                   0 
                THEN
                   f.Growth / 128 
                WHEN
                   1 
                THEN
                   f.growth / 100.00*CAST((f.size / 128.0) AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) 
             END
    ) AS FileSpaceAfterGrowthMB, f.is_percent_growth, file_system_type [File System Type] 
          FROM
             sys.database_files AS f WITH (NOLOCK) 
             INNER JOIN
                sys.master_files m 
                on f.file_id = m.file_id 
             LEFT OUTER JOIN
                sys.data_spaces AS fg WITH (NOLOCK) 
                ON f.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id CROSS APPLY sys.dm_os_volume_stats(database_id, m.file_id) 
          WHERE
             m.database_id = DB_ID()) a' 




     EXEC sp_foreachdb @command = @cmd1, @user_only = 1
     SELECT * 
     FROM #TMP
```

Comment: thanks for the updates but the result is still the same. I read somewhere that this is due to sp_foreachdb or sp_msforeachdb using global cursor and hence why it is not ordered. I also listed the databases to exclude because I have a few non system databases and hence why I marked them as xxes in the script I pasted.

Comment: sp_msforeachdb orders by id, sp_foreachdb orders by name, if you want something different you can modify sp_foreachdb proc

Comment: So use an if to filter your custom databases, the where will return empty

Comment: I updated the answer to exclude your custom tables, system tables are already excluded with the parameter

Comment: Now I don't have the blanks anymore :-). One more question, how do I order the result per instance as opposed to the way it is scattered in multiple grids?

Comment: If you want a single result set you can create a temp table and insert your values there, then, select them as you need it

Comment: Fantastic!!@Daniel thanks a bunch I can now select  and update as needed. Much appreciated.

Comment: I presume if I go through the brent O sp_foreachdb I will find the flag to also include offline/standby etc databases?

Comment: It has a lot of flags and parameter, and since you have the code, you can hack it to add any other filter that you need

Comment: Please, mark the post as helpful or selected answer if I helped you

Comment: @Daniel...I am struggling with being able to also include databases in read only or standby mode even with using the read_only flag...:-(

Comment: For standby mode you can use @state_desc = NULL too but is not possible to access the database in that mode, so you won't be able to get the data with this proc

Comment: Got it all now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello Daniel, thanks for your help with the aforementioned script. I am in need of some extra help with the same script to be able to insert the data from that temp table to a table. I am using central management server to pull out the information but struggling with being able to insert the data into a table in a database on the cms server. I know I am doing something wrong but not sure what :-(. Thanks for your help.

Comment: An straight forward insert-select statement will do it, if not, here is not space enough to properly describe the new problem, and assuming that is nor related to foreachdb is not a good idea to edit this question.... open a new question and post me the link, I 'll be glad to help you

Comment: It is essentially the script above that I run on the cms server to pull out the information but now want to insert that information into a table so not so much a different issue.

Comment: I get errors such as invalid object name 'dba.dbo.filetable' if i add the insert into at the end of the script and run it via central management server.

Answer (score 1):

```
Below is the script with some additions but now unable to insert the output into a 
table.



SET NOCOUNT ON
declare @cmd1 nvarchar(max)
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TMP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TMP

CREATE TABLE #TMP (
    [CheckDate] datetime,
    [DatabaseName] VARCHAR(100),
   [File Name] VARCHAR(200),
   [Physical Name] VARCHAR(200),
   [File - Total Size In MB] FLOAT,
   [File - Available Space In MB] FLOAT,
   [Filegroup Name] VARCHAR(50),
   [Disk Mount Point]  VARCHAR(50),
   [Disk Total Size in GB] FLOAT,
   [Disk Available Size in GB] FLOAT,
   [Disk Free Space % ] FLOAT,
   Growth FLOAT,
   NextGrowthRequirementInMB FLOAT,
   FileSpaceAfterGrowthMB FLOAT)
set @cmd1 =
'use ?
INSERT #TMP
SELECT 
    [CheckDate],
   [DatabaseName],
   [File Name],
   [Physical Name],
   [File - Total Size In MB],
   [File - Available Space In MB],
   [Filegroup Name],
   [Disk Mount Point],
   [Disk Total Size in GB],
   [Disk Available Size in GB],
   [Disk Free Space % ],
   Growth,
   NextGrowthRequirementInMB,
   FileSpaceAfterGrowthMB 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
CONVERT(VARCHAR(24),GETDATE(),121) [CheckDate],
         DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName,
         f.[file_id],
         f.name AS [File Name],
         f.physical_name AS [Physical Name],
         CAST((f.size / 128.0) AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) AS [File - Total Size In MB],
         CAST(f.size / 128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(f.name, ''SpaceUsed'') AS int) / 
128.0 AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) AS [File - Available Space In MB],
         fg.name AS [Filegroup Name],
         volume_mount_point [Disk Mount Point],
         CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), total_bytes / 1073741824.0) AS [Disk Total Size in 
GB],
         ---1GB = 1073741824 bytes 
         CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,2),available_bytes/1073741824.0) AS [Disk Available Size 
in GB], 
         CAST(CAST(available_bytes AS FLOAT) / CAST(total_bytes AS FLOAT) AS 
DECIMAL(18, 2)) * 100 AS [Disk Free Space % ],
         f.Growth,
         CASE
            f.is_percent_growth 
            WHEN
               0 
            THEN
               f.Growth / 128 
            WHEN
               1 
            THEN
               f.growth / 100.00*CAST((f.size / 128.0) AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) 
         END
         AS NextGrowthRequirementInMB, CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), total_bytes / 
1073741824.0) - (
         CASE
            f.is_percent_growth 
            WHEN
               0 
            THEN
               f.Growth / 128 
            WHEN
               1 
            THEN
               f.growth / 100.00*CAST((f.size / 128.0) AS DECIMAL(15, 2)) 
         END
) AS FileSpaceAfterGrowthMB, f.is_percent_growth, file_system_type [File System Type] 
      FROM
         sys.database_files AS f WITH (NOLOCK) 
         INNER JOIN
            sys.master_files m 
            on f.file_id = m.file_id 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN
            sys.data_spaces AS fg WITH (NOLOCK) 
            ON f.data_space_id = fg.data_space_id CROSS APPLY 
sys.dm_os_volume_stats(database_id, m.file_id) 
      WHERE
         m.database_id = DB_ID()) a
ORDER BY 7 desc' 

 EXEC sp_foreachdb @command = @cmd1, @user_only = 1, @exclude_list = '', 
@is_read_only =
NULL
SET NOCOUNT OFF
 SELECT * FROM #TMP
```

Comment: the break lines in [Disk Total Size in GB] and [Disk Available Size in GB] column names are part of the code you are running? or was a bad copy-paste??

Comment: Yes they are and yes bad copy-paste. This is not how I pasted but didn't check it through before sending.

Comment: The line breaks shouldn't be there

Comment: I get errors such as "invalid object name dba.dbo.filetable" if i add the 'insert into' and then select * from #tmp on the central management server

Comment: Then post the error that generate the errors, this part is working

Comment: So I guess I am not doing the right inserts to cater for being able to run the script across multiple instances and inserting into a table on the central management server or any other instance of sql server.

Comment: If I add the instance name like insert into ServerCMS.dbadb.dbo.filetable I get the error message "Could not find server 'ServerCMS' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers." And I don't want to use linkedserver.

Comment: If you want to insert data into a different server/instance you need to create a connection, if you don’t want to use linked server create an ad-hoc connection using OpenDataSource

Comment: Ok I will try that option. In the meantime can you give me examples of the insert statement and where to insert such statement in the script?Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a free code service, there is a lot of places where you can find how to write an insert statement. In the meantime I have my own stuff to do, it also song as you, you are not assigning tasks to a subordinate

Comment: So sorry to have given you that impression. I will not bother you any longer and thanks for your help...much appreciated and all the best with your stuffs.